# Alternative name for *ngIf directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-ng-if

A long time ago Angular 2's docs mentioned an alternate name for `*ngIf`, that didn't use an asterisk. I believe it was something similar to `<prefix>-ng-if` where `<prefix>` was some short prefix.

I cannot find any reference to this in the latest docs.

The use case is that the xml parser I am required to use does not support attributes preceded by '*'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
<template [ngIf]="expr"></template>
```

or

```
<template bind-ngIf="expr"></template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `template` with `[ngIf]`(with Property binding)

```
<template [ngIf]="condition">
  <p>
    Content Goes here
  </p>
</template>
```